# Wordcloud in R: color based on data in other column

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a wordcloud where the color of the wordcloud is based on another column in the dataframe. Hereby I'm using the packages wordcloud2 and RColorBrewer. I'm using the following (sample) code:

```
set.seed(1) 

DF <- data.frame(
  word = c('football','tennis','squash','curling','baseball','diving','archery','cricket','cycling','hockey','formula1','rugby','volleyball','tabletennis','swimming','shooting','taekwondo','judo','handball','horseracing'), 
  freq = sample(100:1000,20), 
  diff = sample(-100:100,20)/100)

library(wordcloud2)
library(RColorBrewer)

color_range_number <- length(unique(DF$diff))
custColorPal <- colorRampPalette(c("#ff0000","#00cc00"))
custColors <- custColorPal(color_range_number)
colors <- custColors[factor(DF$diff)]

wordcloud2(data = DF, color = colors)
```

DF is as follows:

```
          word freq  diff
1     football  339  0.87
2       tennis  434 -0.58
3       squash  614  0.29
4      curling  915 -0.76
5     baseball  280 -0.48
6       diving  904 -0.25
7      archery  945 -0.98
8      cricket  690 -0.26
9      cycling  661  0.67
10      hockey  155 -0.35
11    formula1  283 -0.08
12       rugby  257  0.13
13  volleyball  710 -0.07
14 tabletennis  441 -0.65
15    swimming  782  0.54
16    shooting  540  0.24
17   taekwondo  735  0.46
18        judo  976 -0.81
19    handball  435  0.32
20 horseracing  785  0.93
```

In DF, I'd like to use column 'diff' to assign colors to the words: the more negative the more red, the more positive, the more green.

However, I'm getting unexpected results, such as the fact that 'hockey' is colored green, whereas it should have a more red color due to the value diff of -0.35 for variable 'diff'. See also [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfQUE.png).

I think it is due to the fact that not all words are plotted, since for example 'horseracing' is not plotted.

My questions:

1. Is it correct to state that the colors are 'misassigned' due to the fact that not all words are plotted?
2. How can it made sure that always all words are plotted? Reducing the value of argument 'size' is not always a guarantee. It might be good to note that I'd like to paste this wordcloud via rmarkdown in a PDF.

Comment: To make the example reproducible, use the command `set.seed(1)` at the beginning to make sure the data frame is the same each time.

Comment: Thanks awchisholm, I just changed the description of the question witht the set.seed(1)

Comment: Does the colour always look the same now?

Comment: The results should be consistent now due to the set.seed(1), but the output is still not as what it should be (see my description for e.g. the value 'hockey')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `colors <- custColors[factor(DF$diff)]` is causing the issue I reckon. Try this...

```
    set.seed(1)
    DF <- data.frame(
        word = c('football','tennis','squash','curling','baseball','diving','archery','cricket','cycling','hockey','formula1','rugby','volleyball','tabletennis','swimming','shooting','taekwondo','judo','handball','horseracing'), 
        freq = sample(100:1000,20), 
        diff = sample(-100:100,20)/100) 

    library(wordcloud2)
    library(RColorBrewer)

    color_range_number = nrow(DF)
    custColorPal <- colorRampPalette(c("#ff0000","#00cc00"))
    custColors <- custColorPal(color_range_number)

    wordcloud2(data = DF, color = custColors)
```

All the custColorPal function is doing is a lookup of the diff value to scale it in the range of the colours. Factors are being interpreted as equally spaced numbers in the range 1 to 20.

As for the second question, my suggestion is to make the font small so that there is more chance that all words will be displayed